# rhel + kernel upgrade on physical machine

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, grub2

we have rhel 7.2 server on DELL HW

we upgrade the kernel version to version `3.10.0-693.el7` from previews that was `3.10.0-327.el7`

and we did reboot in order to start the rhel with new kernel version

during boot we select the kernel [image]

but some seconds after this machine was stuck on `CNTR D`  , and machine not started

so we reboot the machine again and select the previous kernel version from the `BAR` - **3.10.0-327.el7**

now machine is up with the old kernel version

I dont sure about this

but is this problem is happens because we not performed the following steps - 1,2

**step 1**

```
grub2-set-default 0
```

note - the list of the kernel are:

```
awk -F\' '$1=="menuentry " {print $2}' /etc/grub2.cfg
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64) 7.2 (Maipo)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64) 7.2 (Maipo)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64) 7.2 (Maipo)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (0-rescue-f3da2dd526e445deadee0bd875b6a246) 7.2 (Maipo)
```

and then

**step 2**

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Answer (score 1):

Request support from RedHat. You're most likely looking at a kernel regression, Grub is unlikely to be the culprit.